# Any image annotation/labeling tool for object detection/recognition (in Windows platform)

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition

I want to label some images as training data for object detection, can be used in windows platform?

Any recommended image annotation tool? (P.S. labelme is not suitable for my purpose as it is web based and my image data are private protected)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can install LabelMe on your own, private server. See https://github.com/CSAILVision/LabelMeAnnotationTool

Comment: Try Dataturks, works right from the browser, no need to install anything.
https://dataturks.com/help/image-rectangle-bounding-box-annotation.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Training Image Labeler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/label-images-for-classification-model-training.html) app in MATLAB.

Comment: It needs Matlab, right? As I may ask some intern students help to label images, they don't have matlab installed as it is not free. Any other recommendation?

Comment: Dataturks works from browser, no worries if windows/linux. Here is an examples: https://dataturks.com/help/image-rectangle-bounding-box-annotation.php

Comment: Try https://oclavi.com

Comment: @AkshaySoam why not make it an answer?

Comment: The question is marked as closed. So can't add a new answer.

Comment: Oh... Well, that's just silly.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I am the developer of this annotation tool.

The [VGG Image Annotator (VIA) tool](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/) should suit your requirements because:

- this tool is based solely on HTML, CSS and Javascript (no external javascript libraries), can be used off-line (full application in a single html file of size < 200KB) and **requires nothing more than a modern web browser** (tested on Firefox, Chrome and Safari)
- you do not need to upload your images and can **run this tool locally in your web browser**. This tool is self contained and does not require any installation.